Can I stop the bottom of my laptop screen from glitching out?
The symptoms can be summed up in this video; screenshot attached:

As far as I can remember, there was always a pink line at the bottom of my laptop (Asus GL502V) screen about a pixel tall. Not enough to be a serious bother. A while back it had a short fall (on carpet) and landed in the back. When I opened it up, it glitched up as far as the taskbar. But, restarting the screen a couple times generally did the trick.
Recently it's just gone up a bit more forcing me to actually take a look inside. I disconnected and reconnected the cable on both ends, one connecting to the screen and the other connecting to the cable. No difference.
What actually is the most likely thing to be damaged here? Is it a simple fix, or expensive enough that I may as well retire my 5 year old laptop?

You could try replacing the cable first. Then, if that doesn't work, take it to a repair shop for a quote.

@DavidPostill I swapped out the cable...nothing got worse screen-wise, but nothing got better, and NOW for some reason by resolution is stuck. It says it's 1920x1080, it's clearly not, and now I can't change it because it's greyed out. Wtf?

If using an external display looks normal, then the issue might be the screen itself. Replacement screens are available for US$60 and up (cited as just an example).
However, the issue could also be due to a broken chip or solder joint, so it is possible you'd replace screen and the issue might not be fixed.
Personally, for a high-end machine such as the Asus GL502V, I'd prefer using it with an external monitor, and add a mechanical keyboard and mouse, and put up with the video glitch only when it must be portable.

It's probably the screen. I just tried replacing the video cable. Didn't fix it, + some weirder symptoms -- see the comments.
